# Is TMPFS okay for my ecommerce portal

Tags: php

How safe is using TMPFS for my ecommerce portal ? Now one question i have in mind: As TMPFS will serve the ram for all work and it will save files in the temporary areas, so is it possible to save those stuffs in asusual ways websites do.

As i am a novice: I am clearing what i mean to say:

Normally if a user uses a php page and posts something in the website ,then the data is saved in the web-page, but what happens for TMPFS ? Kindly brief me about it . So that i can take the advantage of it, properly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmpfs` is no more or less than a RAM disk.

When your server stops or reboots, any data previously in `tmpfs` will disappear.

Comment: (so, no, for god's sake don't use it for your ecommerce portal)

Comment: Then why Magento is reffering to use this ?? You can google it.

Comment: They say to use it for _cache_ - which is by definition something that can go away at any time. So by all means go ahead and use it for the cache directory.